# declare -A returns invalid option using Bash version 5 on apple M1

Tags: bash, docker, macos, shell, apple-m1

I have read similar articles on stackoverflow but none addressing my specific issue, I would really appreciate any help as I am really losing my mind on this one.

1. I have a script that is using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, I have checked the version of bash inside of the script by using echo and it is indeed `bash version 5` that I downloaded via HomeBrew - I read that I do not need to use the path `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` which is where my bash is situated [apple M1 cpu] because of the shebang pasted in point 1.
2. My vsc terminal is using zsh.
3. For some reason even though `declare -A` should be supported by bash versions after 4, I am returned the following error:
   `declare: -A: invalid option declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`
4. My script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION"

# save current branches in packages as `composer install` may change them to master
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$( /usr/bin/dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

DIR=`pwd`

declare -A BRANCHES

DIR=`pwd`

for d in */; do

    cd "$DIR/$d"
    BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

    if [ "${BRANCH}" != "master" ]; then
        BRANCHES[$d]="${BRANCH}"
    fi

done
```

Returned bash version:

```
BASH_VERSION=5.1.16(1)-release
```

Any advice? Please let me know what other details you require. Also, perhaps an alternative syntax to declaring associative arrays, perhaps I cannot declare them before initializing?

I have a subsequent question regarding this as well. This script sits inside of a docker directory - if docker is meant to use the virtual Linux for installations and instances - why then would I need to make certain macOS supported changes to my shell scripts?

Comment: That's the error message you'd get from bash v3.x (like the version standard in macOS), so I'm pretty sure that's what your script is running under. As to *why* that's happening... I don't know enough about your setup, how the script is being run, how your docker container is set up, etc. Try adding `echo "BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION"` within the script, and see what it prints.

Comment: The script you show at 4) doesn't have the shebang you say it does at 1). You don't show how you checked which shell it is running.

Comment: You also don't show how you start the script? If you use `bash yourScript` for example, the shebang will be ignored anyway.

Comment: Apologies @GordonDavisson and, please see my updated code. I had assumed stating it would be enough but I realize now that I could have made a mistake and you would not be able to tell me unless I showed all of the code. New at this :]

Comment: @MarkSetchell Apologies, my code snippet has been updated - thank you for your help though

Comment: I'm still pretty sure it's actually running under bash v3. The source code for bash v5.1.16 does not contain the error message you're getting (instead, it has `"declare [-aAfFgiIlnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]"` in builtins/builtins.c line 78). The version that `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will get depends on the `$PATH` variable in the environment it's run in, and hence will get different versions under different circumstances; I'd change it to `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: (Weirdly, the source for bash v5.1.6 does have the old `declare` option list in one place -- the Turkish translation of the `help declare` message includes `declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [İSİM[=DEĞER] ...]`. I guess that just didn't get updated along with everything else. Some other versions also had the old option list in the Esperanto translation file, but that has been updated in v5.1.16.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your response, I tried the `#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` shebang before I posted this and the same error and same returned shell version - this is such a mind boggler. You are probably right about it still using version 3 but I have checked which bash all over and its version 5 whether its in the script or just my normal terminal

Comment: Did you run your script like this? `chmod +x YOURSCRIPT && ./YOURSCRIPT`