# With homebrew installed bash 5.1.16(1), how do I write shell scripts to make use of string capitalization features?

Tags: bash, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

So the below basic script should output `TEST`, but instead I see `${var^^}: bad substitution` on my M1 based macOS.

```
#!/bin/bash

var='test'
echo ${var^^}
```

My login shell is from homebrew:

```
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
5.1.16(1)-release
$ which bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

It is installed in /etc/shells:

```
$ grep homebrew /etc/shells 
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

The versions of each bash:

```
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Laptop:bash$ /opt/homebrew/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0)
```

Comment: the code works for me (ie, it generates `TEST` under `bash 4.4.12`); what's the output from `/bin/bash --version` ?

Comment: Your `bash` seems to be `bash` version < 4.0 or functions are missing that were introduced with version 4.

Comment: Please try changing `#! /bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash`. No spaces. Please try `bash ./test.sh`. Please add `echo ${BASH_VERSION}` _to the script_, not from the shell.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the only feature `bash` on Apple's M1 is missing, see: [declare -A returns invalid option using Bash version 5 on apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72412436/3776858)

Comment: @markp-fuso: my /bin/version is indeed still at 3, but  I’m not on that bash version at the moment, see edit original post. Are you on M1 tho?

Comment: @N00b13  the problems is that youv'e hardcoded your script (via the shebang = `#!/bin/bash`) to use the old version; one 'easy' fix would be to change your shebang from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/opt/homebrew//bin/bash`; another idea: make sure `/opt/homebrew/bin` is first in your `PATH` and then change your shebang to `#!/bin/env bash`; another idea: copy `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash`, or make `/bin/bash` a symlink to `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` (and leave the script's shebang as `#!/bin/bash`)

Comment: @KamilCuk Holy cow you’re right! If I add echo ${BASH_VERSION} to the script, it states the script is run over 3.2.57(1)-release. But how can it be since I switch with chsh and the above logs states I’m on the homebrew bash which is at version 5.1.16(1)-release ?

Comment: Gosh I didn’t realize /opt/homebrew/bin/bash &  /bin/bash were actually completely different directories in the root. Thx for pointing out my stupidity :\  Which approach is the cleanest tho, copying or the symlink @markp-fuso?

Comment: Thx to all for replying by the way, much appreciated !!

Comment: @N00b13 'cleanest' is a bit subjective; either way you'll need to move the current `/bin/bash` out of the way (perhaps rename as `/bin/bash.3.2.57` in case you need to come back to it at some point?); the symlink is 'clean' but leaves you in a lurch if you happen to remove `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, in which case copying to `/bin/bash` would work

Comment: The cleanest is doing `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, the portable is changing `/bin/bash` to point to your homebrew..

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you use:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

This calls the system bash supplied by Apple, which for macOS Monterey is `3.2.57(1)-release`. This feature you wish to use is available in Bash 4+. It will ignore your login shell and use the hardcoded one in the `test.sh` file.

You have installed bash 5 from brew, so change the script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Or change to:

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```